FastAPI + SQLAlchemy trying to create schema during startup
I am working with Postgres, FastAPI and SQL Alchemy.
I want my application to create the schema and tables from my models during startup. I have the tables from models working fine:
async def migrate_tables() -> None:
    engine =  create_async_engine(api_config.DB_URI)
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        logger.info("CREATING TABLES")
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    logger.info("FINISHED CREATING TABLES")

This code is run from the main.py by use of lifespan
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(api: FastAPI):
    await migrate_tables()
    yield

api = FastAPI(title="Explorer API", lifespan=lifespan)

I am not sure if that is the best way to do it, so any suggestions on that are welcome as well.
Now for the creation of the schema, I don't have so much luck, got a couple suggestions from the web, all similar to these: SQLAlchemy: "create schema if not exists"
But none of them worked for me. What I tried was to create another method to run to create the schema:
def create_schema():
    schema_name = 'my_schema'
    engine = create_engine(api_config.SYNC_DB_URI)
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(CreateSchema(schema_name, if_not_exists=True))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        yield

And then add it before the migrate_tables() one. But it does not work.
Things to consider. The create_engine on the tables uses postgresql+asyncpg. The engine on the schema is using just postgressql. I read somewhere that asyncpg did not went well with the schema part so I tried using a non async engine, but it fails the same.
Other thing I did try was to add the create schema on the same migrate_table right before the command that create the tables:
await connection.run_sync(CreateSchema('my_schema'))
It fails with message:
TypeError: ExecutableDDLElement.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bind'

Any suggestions on how I achieve the creation of the schema before creating my tables from the models?

usually tables has to be created only once - so there is no need to keep this code in running web server. I would create separate script to create tables.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Also - be aware that this won't actually do any migrations, so you'll end up with your database not matching your models if you change anything afterwards. You probably want to use Alembic to handle your database definitions instead of create_all.

You should be able to hook in your schema creation before the metadata is all created by setting this event before you call create_all.
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

@event.listens_for(Base.metadata, 'before_create')
def receive_before_create(target, connection, **kw):
    connection.execute(CreateSchema('justsomeschema'))


It's a good practice to split migrations and logic itself. I would suggest you to use alembic for your purposes. It allows you to easily manage your db schema, make changes to it, or roll them back.
After implementation your migrations all you will need is to execute alembic upgrade head after starting your db. If your db schema is relevant no changes will be made. In case some tables have been changed, alembic will apply only the missing migrations. This is an extremely convenient and useful tool that goes well with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy.
You can do something like this to apply all migrations on starting an app:
alembic upgrade head && uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --reload asgi:app


I just want to supplement Victor's answer, and point out that there is a pattern to start a FastAPI + SQLAlchemy application
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=get_engine())
    yield


app = FastAPI(title="User Authentication Demo", lifespan=lifespan)

